# How to force Taskscheduler start my batches properly?

Tags: windows, batch-file, task-scheduler

OS: Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise

**My aim:** I want to start my InfluxDB and Grafana-servers on log-on with Task sheduler.

**What I have**: Two batches which **are working right** when I start them manually.  The look like this:

start_grafana.bat:

```
title grafana
call [path_to_grafana]
```

start_influx.bat:

```
title influxDB
call [path_to_influxDB]
```

**Problem:** When I log on with my user Task scheduler starts influxDb process but without a cmd window (somewhere in the background), what is not preferred. And do not start grafana at all.

I don't understand what the problem is. Could you please point me in the right direction or give info where I could search for answers?

**Remark1:** Task Scheduler history shows:
Task started
Action started
Created Task Process
Action completed
Action started
Created Task Process

When I understand it right, the first "action" is grafana, it stops. The second is influx - it stops not. Why does stops grafana?

Answer (score 0):

I setup something similar using the unlock workstation event and it launches a cmd window as expected. 
Here's something you can try.  In your run command for the task, specify `cmd.exe /k` for the command and your batch file for an argument. `/k` tells cmd.exe not to exit after it execute the command.  This should keep the window around.